# Which penalties are possible when switching from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: seo, google, https, pagerank, google-ranking

When switching our website from HTTP to HTTPS, things went catastrophic:

- Page impressions went down from average 60 (peak 110) to below 10 (per day).
- Traffic from search engines dropped to zero.
- In other words, we became almost invisible on Google.

**What caveats may we have missed?**

This is what we did:

- Using a commercial SSL certificate (i.e. no self-signed or CAcert)
- Using the exact same domain name as before (i.e. no "www." before and after)
- Using 301 redirects for each HTTP page to its HTTPS version
- Internal links are all relative URLs (before and after)
- Same content, except for chaging "link rel=canonical" URLs from HTTP to HTTPS
- Google webmaster tools don't show anything suspicious.
- robots.txt is unchanged, containts just two lines `User-agent: *` and `Disallow: /wp-admin/` (The last one is a leftover. there is no Wordpress running. These are static, cleaned-up pages)

As far as I can tell, we did everything that is recommended by SEO blogs and other StackExchange answers (such as https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/68089/48957).

**Solved!**

Thanks for all helpful comments!

Technically, everything was correct. However, it was necessary to **add the HTTPS website as a new entry to GWT**. Then, the old HTTP entry still had the dropping impressions, but the new HTTPS entry caught on and now has as many impression as the old HTTP entry had before.

Comment: Did you change your managed sites or look at Google's webmaster tools? The answer might be there.

Comment: @Rob: Yes, we did. Thanks for the hint, I added it to the post.

Comment: Over what time period are your 60 page views?   Per minute, per hour, per day?

Comment: The list of things you did look perfect to me.   Have you checked *robots.txt*?   Have you used "fetch as Google" from WMT?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller: Per day. robots.txt is unchanged, see description. Addeded both to description, thanks.

Comment: Did your pagespeed change? Or maybe you've created dead internal links?

Comment: Everything you have listed here looks fine.  Can you include a link to your site that we can look over for anything unexpected?